# How to make memcache accessible only from several ip's?

Tags: security, memcache

I have 4 load balansed apache servers, that are using one memcache server. I want to make memcache server accessible only from my this 4 servers. How can I do it?

Can I write something like this in memcache's config?

```
-l 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3, 127.0.0.4
```

Comment: Have you tried consulting the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewConfiguringServer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with memcached itself.
Your options will only tell to listen on those (loopback) addresses but not limit the access to them at all.
Memcached is meant to be deployed in trusted networks only.

If you want to limit connections to certain IPs to your memcached instance you need to do this at another layer (e.g. via iptables).